# Why the print out looks like this?

Tags: python

```
class Person:
    pets=[]
    def add_pet(self, pet):
        self.pets.append(pet)

jane = Person()
bob = Person()

jane.add_pet("cat")
print(jane.pets)
print(bob.pets)
```

Print out:

```
['cat']
['cat']
```

why bob's pets is also cats? I didn't append pets to bob.

Comment: because `pets` is not an instance member, but a class member.

Comment: because Jane and Bob are married and they both own the `pet`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you share the variable pets with every instance of Person.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pets = []

    def add_pet(self, pet):
        self.pets.append(pet)
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The list `pets` is shared between all objects in the class because of where you declare it.  You need a *constructor*, called `__init__`, which is called automagically when the object is created:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pets = []

    def add_pet(self, pet):
        self.pets.append(pet)


jane = Person()
bob = Person()

jane.add_pet("cat")
print(jane.pets)
print(bob.pets)
```

Gives:

```
['cat']
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting the pets to be an instance member:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pets = []
    ...
```

Output:

```
['cat']
[]
```